# Use a period as a separator in php

Tags: php

say i have `first.last` or maybe `Bob.Dylan`

Can i can break it apart?

So i have `$first` and `$last`

So the variable for first would be Bob.
and the Variable for last would be Dylan.

I was thinking php split but its DEPRECATED.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) instead.

Comment: Thanks! I got ` $fullname = explode(".", $username);
   $first = $fullname[0];
   $last = $fullname[1]; `

Answer (score 9):

Try using [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) with `list`

```
$string = "first.last";
if( strpos( $string, "." ) === FALSE )
    throw new Exception( "string doesn't contain a '.'" );

list( $first, $last ) = explode( ".", $string, 2 );
```

*Note: it's important that `$string` contains a "." or you'll get a error. You can check that it does via `strpos`.*

Also when trying to find an alternative function for one that is deprecated, it's a good idea to start with the list of *"Also See"* functions on the deprecated function's [documentation page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.split.php). In this case `explode` is in that list.

Comment: You might want to add the third optional parameter `$limit` to the `explode()` call so that if you run into `first.middle.last`, it won't loose data...  `list($first, $last) = explode('.', $name, 2);`

Answer (score 4):

use `explode('.',$var)`

Answer (score 2):

More explicit

```
list($first,$last) = explode('.', $string, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

`sscanf()` is a great, single-call to parse a strictly formatted string.  Add variables as additional parameters in the call and they will retain the matches respectively.

The pattern says: greedily match non-dot characters, the match the literal dot, then greedily match non-whitespace characters.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/I3Z0F))

```
$string = 'Bob.Dylan';
sscanf($string, '%[^.].%s', $first, $last);
var_export($first);
echo "\n";
var_export($last);
```

Output:

```
'Bob'
'Dylan'
```